# Two images with movement

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am doing a personal project and now I have thought of placing two ships, one ship would have to be bouncing (ship2.png) without me controlling it and the other ship would have to handle it with the arrows on the keyboard (ship.png).

The problem is that when I want to add the image "ship2.png" it seems to be overwritten and no longer places the image "ship.png".

I have already loaded the image in the section **this.loadImages = function()**

The problem is in this part:  *object.ship = new spaceship(200, 100,object.images["ship"]);* if I add "ship2" it overwrites and no longer shows me "ship".

Comment: Can you explain this part : "the other ship would have to handle it with the arrows on the keyboard (ship.png)." Currently, the arrow keys allow me to change the direction of `ship2` and `ship` is not present on the screen. What should `ship` do exactly?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't explain well.
The first objective is to control ship.png with the keyboard dates (this is already done).
The second objective is to place a second ship (ship2.png) that moves randomly on the screen (I don't know how to do this).

Comment: That is, while "ship2.png" moves randomly around the screen, I can control the movements of "ship.png" without affecting the movements of "ship2.png".

Comment: The reason you are unable to add a new ship to your canva is because your `animation()` class has a single spaceship object initially initialized as `this.ship=null`. To be able to add another ship, you will have to create a second spaceship object using `new Spaceship()`. Then you will have to modify all the functions in your animation class  by adding a new parameter `currentship`. Finally, when calling each function in the animation class, you will have to specify the ship.

Comment: So for example instead of `object.displacement`, you might want to implement something like `object.displacement(ship2)` to displace only `ship2` and `object.displacement(ship)` to displace only `ship`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I was able to solve it correctly.

Comment: Great! Now post an answer which explains how you solved your problem and accept your own answer to inform others that your problem has been resolved.